# How to access form control from a method within same form in C#?

Tags: c#

My server form accepts connection request from client and then i need to add ip address of connected clients in a list box named lstIP.But im unable to access lstIP from OnClientConnect method.help would be appreciated.Here is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public int cpuLoad;
        private PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
      static  public string curIP;
       public static string get_localip = GetLocalIP();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitialiseCPUCounter();
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblServerIP.Text += " "+get_localip;
        }
          private static TcpListener _listener;

           public static void StartServer() 
    {
         System.Net.IPAddress localIPAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(get_localip);
        IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(localIPAddress, 8888);
        _listener = new TcpListener(ipLocal);
        _listener.Start();
        WaitForClientConnect();

    }
    private static void WaitForClientConnect()
    {
        object obj = new object();
        _listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new System.AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), obj);
    }
    public static void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        try
        {

            TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
           // Socket sck;


            clientSocket = _listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(asyn);
         IPAddress add= IPAddress.Parse(((IPEndPoint)clientSocket.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString());
         curIP = add.ToString();

          Form1 myform=new Form1();
          myform.items.add("client connectes with ip:"+curIP);
          **// lstIP.items.add("client connected with ip"+curIP); 
        // MessageBox.Show("cleint connected with ip:"+ curIP);**

            HandleClientRequest clientReq = new HandleClientRequest(clientSocket);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        WaitForClientConnect();
    }

    public void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartServer();


    }
    private void InitialiseCPUCounter()
    {
        cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter(
        "Processor",
        "% Processor Time",
        "_Total",
        true
        );
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cpuLoad = Convert.ToInt32(cpuCounter.NextValue());
        this.txtCPUusage.Text =
 cpuLoad.ToString() +
 "%";
    }
  static  public string GetLocalIP()
    {
        IPHostEntry host;
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                return ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        return "127.0.0.1";
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: What's not working? `add` variable should have the public IP of the socket connected.

Comment: I am unable to access lstbox(lstIP) from within onclientconnect method

Comment: You get `InvalidOperationException`? If so [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c?rq=1) should help you.

Comment: Did you check the other part of your partial class? How does your listBox "lstIP" look like in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. You're inside a `static` method. You can't access instance fields inside a static member without the reference of the object.

I mean you need something like

```
myForm.lstIP.items.add("client connected with ip"+curIP);
```

But, I suggest you to avoid static and make all the methods instance, then everything will be fine.

Also note that `OnClientConnect` will be called in worker thread, so you can't update the UI over there. Refer [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c) for more info.

Note: Please post what errors you get, and do mention that whether it is a compile time error or runtime Exception. *im unable to access XXX*, *It is not working* are not helpful for us to understand the problem. [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)

---

Your complete code will look like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public int cpuLoad;
    private PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
    static public string curIP;
    public static string get_localip = GetLocalIP();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitialiseCPUCounter();
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblServerIP.Text += " " + get_localip;
    }
    private TcpListener _listener;

    public void StartServer()
    {
        System.Net.IPAddress localIPAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(get_localip);
        IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(localIPAddress, 8888);
        _listener = new TcpListener(ipLocal);
        _listener.Start();
        WaitForClientConnect();

    }
    private void WaitForClientConnect()
    {
        object obj = new object();
        _listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new System.AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), obj);
    }
    public void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
            // Socket sck;

            clientSocket = _listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(asyn);
            IPAddress add = IPAddress.Parse(((IPEndPoint)clientSocket.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString());
            curIP = add.ToString();

            //Use this.Invoke or this.BeginInvoke
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                lstIP.items.add("client connected with ip" + curIP);
                MessageBox.Show("cleint connected with ip:" + curIP);
            }));

            HandleClientRequest clientReq = new HandleClientRequest(clientSocket);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        WaitForClientConnect();
    }

    public void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartServer();
    }
    private void InitialiseCPUCounter()
    {
        cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter(
        "Processor",
        "% Processor Time",
        "_Total",
        true
        );
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cpuLoad = Convert.ToInt32(cpuCounter.NextValue());
        this.txtCPUusage.Text = cpuLoad.ToString() + "%";
    }
    static public string GetLocalIP()
    {
        IPHostEntry host;
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                return ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        return "127.0.0.1";
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried it too.My list box remains empty even after instanciating form1.i do not know why.

Comment: when i made onClientConnect instance,i found access denied for other methods like(waitforclient etc) which are all static

Comment: @ayna Make that also static. Except `GetLocalIP` method all other has to be instance methods. So obviously `_listener;` field also needs to be instance field.

Comment: Updated my answer, Not tested but that should work. If not let me know. btw you need a beginner tutorial on what `static` and instance are how they differ.